# using date format instead of linux time

Tags: php, sql

I usually convert date to linux time so i will be able to select records between two dates.

for instance:

```
WHERE create_date > 1443627575 AND create_date < 1443637575
```

is it possible to select data using dates (without converting them to linux time)?
for instance:

```
WHERE create_date > 20-03-2015 AND create_date < 25-03-2015
```

also, can I change the date format in my MySQL so it will be dd/mm/yy ?

Comment: You can select like this 
WHERE create_date BETWEEN '20-03-2015' AND '25-03-2015'
and
Yes you can change date format in mysql calling this - DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')

Comment: If your first query works fine, does that means you store the date in unix format? Is it integer?

Comment: so for what reason do we need to use linux time at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select like this
 `WHERE create_date BETWEEN '20-03-2015' AND '25-03-2015'`

and Yes you can change date format in mysql calling this -

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')
```

*put   your date for NOW

Comment: Yes you can insert like this 

INSERT INTO yourtable
  VALUES ('val1', 'val2' , STR_TO_DATE('8-11-2015', '%d-%m-%Y') ) ;

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`STR_TO_DATE`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [**`BETWEEN`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) :

```sql
WHERE create_date BETWEEN 
    STR_TO_DATE('20-03-2015', '%d-%m-%Y') and 
    STR_TO_DATE('25-03-2015', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: no, i mean - INSERT INTO table create_date VALUE 20-03-2015  (day, month and than year)

Comment: @Roi, yes - as a string? and then `BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(<fieldName>, '%d-%m-%Y') and 
    STR_TO_DATE(<fieldName>, '%d-%m-%Y')` I use it as such, and also with year, day, and months separated out in different fields that is concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `from_unixtime` function.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE from_unixtime(create_date) BETWEEN '20-03-2015' AND '25-03-2015'

//date should be with in quotes
```